# Number of given order subgroups of the torsion subgroup (Elliptic Curve)

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography, torsion-groups, isogeny

I'm studing the paper "ON THE COST OF COMPUTING ISOGENIES BETWEEN
SUPERSINGULAR ELLIPTIC CURVES" ([link](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/313.pdf)) and, at some point, autors say that (assuming $e$ even):

the number of order-$\ell^{e/2}$ subgroups of $E[\ell^e]$ is $N=(\ell+1)\ell^{e/2 - 1}.$

Here $E$ is an elliptic curve on $\mathbb{F}_q,$ $q = p^n$ with $p$ prime and $\ell$ is another prime diffrent from $p$. $E[\ell^{e}]$ is the set of $\ell^e-$torsion points of the elliptic curve $E$.

Can someone help me to understand why the number of order-$\ell^{e/2}$ subgroups of $E[\ell^e]$ is $N=(\ell+1)\ell^{e/2 - 1}$?

I know that $E[\ell^{e}] \simeq \mathbb{Z}/\ell^e \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\ell^e \mathbb{Z}$ so i think that the problem is equivalent to counting  order-$\ell^{e/2}$ subgroups of  $\mathbb{Z}/\ell^e \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\ell^e \mathbb{Z}.$ But

- I'm unable to do it;
- I'm not convinced I'm on the right way.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the number of **cyclic** subgroups.

If $c\le e$ then any subgroup of order $\ell^c$ in $E[\ell^e]$ will be contained in $E[\ell^c]$. The number of
elements of order $\ell^c$ in $\Bbb{Z}/\ell^c\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}/\ell^c\Bbb{Z}$ is $\ell^{2c}-\ell^{2(c-1)}$ (elements $(a,b)$ with $\ell\nmid a$ or $\ell \nmid b$). Then divide by $\ell^{c-1}(\ell-1)$ (the number of elements generating the same subgroup) to get $\ell^{c-1}(\ell+1)$ for the number of **cyclic** subgroups of order $\ell^c$.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have last question for you. Here ([link](https://martindale.info/talks/CWI-notbreakSIDH.pdf)), p. 37/59, C. Martindale and  L. Panny give an example: consider two elliptic curves E and E' over $\mathbb{F}_{431}$ (explicit) which are 4-isogenous. Obviously they write  that an 4-isogeny $f:E\to E'$ has ker generated by $P\in E[\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}]$ of order $4.$ Why do they say "try all nine possible order 4 kernels..."? With respect with your argouments i think that possible 4 order Kernels are six. I'm wrong?

Comment: @ManuelBravi Not hard to check by hand that there are $6$ cyclic subgroups of order $4$. The only non-cyclic one is $C_2\times C_2$ but it is the kernel of $P\to [2]P$ so it would need that the two curves have the same $j$-invariant (and be in fact isomorphic over $\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p$)